# HDRI image is visible through glass in a PNG transparent render. How to remove it?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri

... and also keep the light and reflections. What I'm trying achieve is on the second picture.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/188soBP5s7MmlA6hqWQjNV_fNkuiOTO9i/view?usp=sharing)

[image: What i get now]
[image: This is how i need to render]

Comment: Are you using EEVEE or Cycles? I think there is a setting somewhere that allows glass to behave transparently like this for compositing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around in **EEVEE** is to fake the reflection on top of your transparent object

This is what you need for the transparent object to have.

1 **Alpha Blend** inside settings

2 A texture coordinate, eviroment node, Glossy BSDF and a transparent node.

Once you have that, you need to connect the texture coordinate node  reflection to enviroment, enviroment to glossy and combine glossy + transparent using a mix shader node.

**Make sure to use the same HDRI for your material and your world**

Like this:

[image]

to make it more transparent, use the mix shader factor.

Hope that helps